# Get object property dynamically using variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object like this

```
var item={"Financials":0,"Risk":3,"Issue":2,"Milestone":1};

getRAG(n:number):string{
  ...
  ...
  Return 'myclass';
}
```

and the template looks like this

```
<div>
  <i [ngClass]="getRAG(item.Financials)">
</div>
```

But in the above template I specified the value I needed which is item.Financials.

So I have updated the template as

```
<div>
  <i [ngClass]="getRAG(item['Financials'])">
</div>
```

expecting I can provide the variable name to replace 'Financials' there

So I created the variable

```
val:string="Financials";
```

and rewritten the template as

```
<div>
  <i [ngClass]="getRAG(item[val])">
</div>
```

But its not working as expected. The value from `val` variable is not considering correctly in the item object.

I was expecting when the variable changed to this

```
val="Risk"
```

it should return the Risk score within the function.

Please share your thoughts on how to handle this.

Comment: When you do this, what is the value of val you see in the template? Where are you updating this value? Can you add Ts code?

Comment: why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Answer (score 0):

When using functions to return a class, to be able to determine if the function returns the expected value and class, some console output within the function can distinguish the value being passed from the `ngClass` selector.

You can setup the method in your Typescript code to provide this as follows:

```
getRAG(n: number): string {
  console.log('param value:' + n);
  switch (n) {
    case 0:
      return 'myclassR';
    case 1:
      return 'myclassG';
    case 2:
      return 'myclassB';
    case 3:
      return 'myclassY';
  }
  return 'myclassD';
}
```

Create some CSS classes with distinct font colors like so:

```
.myclassR {
  font-size: large;
  color: red;
}

.myclassG {
  font-size: large;
  color: green;
}

.myclassB {
  font-size: large;
  color: blue;
}

.myclassY {
  font-size: large;
  color: yellow;
}

.myclassD {
  font-size: large;
  color: purple;
}
```

Within the HTML element `<i>`, include text to see the effect of the above classes:

```
<div>
  <i [ngClass]="getRAG(item.Financials)">hello1</i>
</div>

<br />

<div>
  <i [ngClass]="getRAG(item['Financials'])">hello2</i>
</div>

<br />

<div>
  <i [ngClass]="getRAG(item[val])">hello3</i>
</div>

<br />
```

When the above is executed, changing the variable `val` that is passed into the function `getRag()` will be output in the console and the style of the text within the `<i>` element will change.

When the value of variable `val` is set to 'Risk', the resulting color of the text rendered will be yellow
from class `myclassY`.